# Changing traits at runtime

Tags: php, traits

I have defined a Product Class which uses the following Trait:

```
trait ArrayableTrait {
    function toArray() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

I wonder if i can change the ArrayableTrait that Product Class is using to another at runtime.

```
trait CustomArrayableTrait {
    function toArray() {
        return array(
            'code' => $this->getCode(),
            'name' => $this->getName(),
            //etc
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using autoloading, I would think you could do

```
use CustomArrayableTrait as ArrayableTrait;
```

Comment: That is not what i am asking